# connect to neo4j auradb behind a proxy by python api

Tags: python, neo4j, proxy

I got a neo4j auradb instance like `neo4j+s://12345678.databases.neo4j.io`, I can access it by browser behind a proxy `http://username:Password@ip:port` in my organization network, but by a local `demo.py` I failed.

I looked into official demo:
https://neo4j.com/docs/aura/auradb/connecting-applications/python/,

and py2neo:
https://py2neo.org/2021.1/

but found nothing about `proxy` configurations neither.

I also tried `export {http_proxy,https_proxy,HTTP_PROXY,HTTPS_PROXY,ALL_PROXY}=http://username:Password@ip:port` before `python3 ./demo.py`,

and tried add below in `demo.py`:

```py
import os 
proxy = "http://username:Password@ip:port"
os.environ["http_proxy"] = proxy
os.environ["https_proxy"] = proxy
os.environ["ALL_PROXY"] = proxy
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = proxy
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = proxy
```

but looks no help and no difference.

by official demo, I got

```
Unable to retrieve routing information
Transaction failed and will be retried in 0.860454196033946s (Unable to retrieve routing information)
...
...
...
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Unable to retrieve routing information
```

by py2neo demo, I got

```
py2neo.errors.ServiceUnavailable: Cannot connect to any known routers
```

can I get some advice? thanks

Comment: Pls show us your entire code not a partial code. Thx

Comment: neo4j's bolt is under tcp, not http, hence you will need to use a socks proxy